# javax.mail.MessagingException: Failed to load IMAP envelope（Android development）

Tags: jakarta-mail

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPYsd.png)

JavaMail 1.6.0 official version, getFrom parsed exception.

Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello! Please provide more information.

Comment: Use JavaMail IMAP to receive e-mail mail, it will appear this error, maybe the error is the server problem, there have been the existence of this error, when I use Javamail, I now use the JavaMail1.6.0, Just released the latest version

Comment: @Mr.Boudar Learn how to use SO, this is the wrong way.

Comment: Other mailbox is possible, but thank you.

Comment: May be because I can only set up the last 30 days of e-mail, so javaMail that can not pull the envelope, the explanation on the reasonable, or thank you!

Comment: Haha, to solve this problem, okay...